How to import a custom embedding model into ollama
I have tried to convert hf model to gguf, and then import into ollama. But I got some problem.

When I tried model like m3e-large (https://huggingface.co/moka-ai/m3e-large)，I successfully imported, and I can run command :

ollama run m3e-large

but when I use it with the code below:
import ollama

embeddings = ollama.embeddings(
  model='MiniLM-L6:v2',
  prompt=['Llamas are members of the camelid family'],
)

print(embeddings)

I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\LocalLLM\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    embeddings = ollama.embeddings(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "L:\Software\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\ollama\_client.py", line 281, in embeddings
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "L:\Software\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\ollama\_client.py", line 75, in _request
    raise ResponseError(e.response.text, e.response.status_code) from None
ollama._types.ResponseError


When I try model like MiniLM-L6 (https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2), the command ollama run MiniLM-L6:V2 returns:

Error: "MiniLM-L6:V2" does not support generate

